# Expanding label widget to fill cell width using grid

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

trying to get the label to fill the cell entirely using tkinter in Python. I have tried this code, and essentially IMO I am not able to get 'EW' to work. Please help!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='#696969')
root.title('Title')
root.geometry('310x510')
root.resizable(False, False)


f = Frame(root, width=300, height=500, bg='silver', bd=0, cursor='arrow', highlightbackground='silver', highlightcolor='silver', highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT)
f.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 0, ipady = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = 'NSEW')
f.grid_propagate(0)

l = Label(f, text = 'Algorithms', justify = CENTER, bd = 0, anchor = CENTER, bg = '#313233', fg = 'white', wraplength = 0, font = 'Helvetica 9 bold')
l.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0, ipadx = 0, ipady = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = 'EW')
l.grid_propagate(0)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the Label *does* fill the cell completely. The problem is that the column is only as wide as its contents, which is the width of the Label. You could make the Label, and therefore the column, wider by using `width=...` on the Label, but it would be difficult to make it exactly as wide as you want because the width of a Label is measured in character units.

What you really want is the column to expand to the width of the Frame. You can do this by giving the column a `weight` with [`columnconfigure`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190528193253/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-config.html). Unused width is distributed to columns with a non-zero `weight`, relative to the `weigth` they have (a column with `weight=2` will get twice the space of a column with `weight=1`). Because you only have one column, you can basically use any non-zero number to distribute all unused space to this column. Since we're talking about the grid inside the Frame, you should call `columnconfigure` on the Frame widget:

```
f.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: Hi! It worked and the concept is also much clearer to me now. thanks a ton for explaining in detail! I love this community!!! <3

Comment: You're very welcome. Since this is still one of you first questions, you might might be interested in reading the ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) page from the Help Center if you haven't already.